# обнуление массива без memset

Tags: c++, ассемблер

здравствуйте, не могу понять следующий выхлоп:

```
ex::ex():
movq    $0, (%rdi)
movq    $0, 992(%rdi)
movq    %rdi, %rcx
leaq    8(%rdi), %rdi
xorl    %eax, %eax
andq    $-8, %rdi
subq    %rdi, %rcx
addl    $1000, %ecx
shrl    $3, %ecx
rep stosq
ret
```

для кода:

```
class ex {
  public:
  ex() :a{0} {}
  char a[1000];
};

int main() {
    ex a;
}
```

читал, что  rep stosq делает примерно то же, что и цикл, заполняя что-то пока ecx > 0, вот только не могу толком понять что. в подобных вопросах говорят, что вроде edi заполняется значениями из eax... однако полного понимания  как достигается обнуление массива в 1000 элементов нету... разъясните по инструкциям что там и зачем, сдвиг на 3 или вот это, например, зачем:

```
movq    $0, (%rdi)
movq    $0, 992(%rdi)
```

обновление: в общем, предыдущий выхлоп был с -fno-inline, без него генерится вот это:

```
    subq    $1016, %rsp
    movl    $125, %ecx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    rep stosq
```

вопрос тот же: что за треш с rep stosq?

Comment: Ассемблерный код с оптимизациями (т.е. `g++ -S -O2 ...` или `-Os`) значительно понятней человеку. (попробуйте. Только учтите, что такая программа превратится в `xorl %eax, %eax`, `ret`. Так что просто добавьте в конце вызов какой-нибудь фиктивной функции и передайте в нее `a` по ссылке)

Comment: @avp, ну я использовал еще -fno-inline чтобы чисто посмотреть что будет... ща обновлю вопрос без -fno-inline

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем ваши трудности с последним вариантом. Там вообще все тривиально. Прописано 125 явных итераций. Какой "треш"?

Comment: Вот, последний фрагмент хорош. В стеке резервируется место для `a` (1000 байт на вершине). Этот адрес пересылается в `%rdi` (один из  операндов `stosq`), второй ее операнд (`%rax`) обнуляется, устанавливаем операнд `rep` (`%ecx`) и выполняем 125 раз `stosq` (`rep` будет уменьшать `%ecx` и увеличивать `%rdi`)

Comment: Вообще, вот описание [rep](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_279.html) (в комментарии раньше немного ошибся, на самом деле `%rdi` увеличивает команда `stosq`, а не `rep`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Сдвиг на 3 нужен потому, что компилятор желает использовать инструкцию `rep stosq`, которая заполняет память не побайтно, а по 8-байтным словам. Поэтому количество итераций, которое надо сделать инструкции `rep stosq` равно размеру буфера, деленному на 8. Это и есть сдвиг вправо на 3.

  То есть при подходе "в лоб" надо просто сделать 125 итераций `rep stosq`.
- Однако для того, чтобы `rep stosq` работала эффективнее, необходимо, чтобы ее целевой адрес был выровнен на границу 8 байт. Ваш буфер `a` не гарантированно выровнен на границу 8 байт. Поэтому компилятор делает следующее: первое и последнее 8-байтное слово вашего буфера обнуляются индивидуально. Именно это делают инструкции

  ```
  movq    $0, (%rdi)
  movq    $0, 992(%rdi)
  ```

  А далее компилятор вычисляет выровненный на границу 8 байт адрес, с которого надо начать обнуление оставшейся "серединки" вашего буфера

  ```
  leaq    8(%rdi), %rdi
  andq    $-8, %rdi
  ```

  а также вычисляет, сколько надо сделать итераций `rep stosq`, чтобы обнулить эту "серединку". Для вычисления количества итераций мы вычитаем из `ecx` (который в этот момент содержит точное начало буфера), значение выровненного начала

  ```
  subq    %rdi, %rcx
  ```

  Если произошло фактическое выравнивание, то значение `rcx` станет *отрицательным* (более того, даже при выровненном буфере `rdi` здесь содержит адрес *второго* слова, т.е. значение `rcx` в любом случае будет отрицательным). Затем

  ```
  addl    $1000, %ecx
  shrl    $3, %ecx
  ```

  вычислит требуемое количество итераций, которое в общем случае получится меньше, чем 125 (т.е. 124).

Comment: А почему `xor eax, eax`, а не `xor rax, rax`? откуда берутся 8-байтные нули, если в eax только 4 байта?

Comment: Да, и почему "Итераций получится меньше, чем 125"? Ведь в %ecx записывается константа: `addl    $1000, %ecx
shrl    $3, %ecx`

Comment: @vp_arth: О, это странная-интересная фича интеловских 64-битных платформ - обнуление `eax` автоматически обнуляет весь `rax`. См. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register

Comment: @Sergey Slepov: Там не "записывается константа", там *прибавляется* константа. К этому моменту в `ecx` потенциально будет сидеть *отрицательное* значение, полученное `subq    %rdi, %rcx`. То есть сумма будет 1000 или *меньше* и после деления на 8 даст 125 или *меньше*.

Comment: @Ant, чет жесть какая-то... можете прокомментить обновленный вопрос, а то не понятно до сих пор

Comment: @xperious: Не понимаю, в чем ваши трудности с последним вариантом. Там вообще все тривиально. Прописано 125 явных итераций. Какой "треш"?

Comment: ну вот по шагам: добавляем к указателю на вершину стека 1016, в ecx кладем 125, обнуляем eax, указатель на вершину стека засовываем в rdi... а дальше то что?) что за магия то, еще раз

Comment: @xperious: `rep stosq` - это инструкуция, которая, начиная с адреса в `rdi`, пробежится по 8-байтовым словам памяти в количестве `rcx` и сохранит в каждое слово содержимое `rax`. Так как в `rax` сидит ноль, получаем обнуление 125 последовательных 8-байтных слов. Это и есть ваш буфер размером 1000 байт.

Comment: @Ant, ааа, вот теперь ясно, я то думал что доходим до rep stosq и, как в цикле, возвращаемся и заново идем до нее... благодарствую... непонятно только почему xor %eax, %eax, почему сразу не сделать xor %rax, %rax

Comment: @xperious: Потому что эффект тот же, а `xor %eax, %eax` меньше по размеру.

Comment: @xperious `xor rax, rax` - это тот же `xor eax, eax`, но со специальным байтом-префиксом `rex`. Нет смысла использовать более длинную инструкцию, если более короткая даст тот же эффект.

Comment: @Ant, возможно, вопрос глупый, но все же: а откуда инфа, что верхняя часть регистра rax тоже нулевая? вот обнуляем мы eax, а rax ненулевой останется все равно... или компилятору известно что rax точно пустой?

Comment: @xperious, eax это младшие 32 разряда rax (и да, компилятор знает, что обнуляя eax он также обнуляет и старшие разряды rax) ([регистры x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#x86_registers))

Comment: @xperious: Я уже отвечал и давал ссылку выше. Любые инструкции 64-битной архитектуры, которые формируют результат в `eax`, автоматически обнуляют верхнюю часть `rax`. Это относится ко всем регистрам.

Comment: @Ant, а да, я чет проглядел...